# Correr un .exe con un archivo Powershell (.ps1)

Tags: powershell, exe

Necesito saber como correr un archivo .exe (o .bat) directamente con un archivo Powershell.
Tengo 2 archivos en la misma carpeta, uno llamemosle prueba.exe y tengo otro llamado prueba2.ps1. Adentro del archivo powershell tengo:

```
./prueba.exe
```

El problema es que cuando hago click en el ps1 me abre el editor de texto y no ejecuta el comando. Tengo que hacer click derecho y ejecutar con Powershell para que lo corra.

Alguien sabe como se puede automatizar este proceso? Agradezco cualquier ayuda!

Comment: Cambia la asociación del tipo de archivo .ps1 en Windows, para que lo abra con powershell y no con el powershell ISE o con bloc de notas, etc

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda Alfabravo, como puedo cambiar la asociación de un archivo utilizando cmd o powershell?

Comment: Hace más de diez años que la gente viene pidiendo una manera fácil de correr un script.  Tal vez esta respuesta te ayude.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137146/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-powershell-script-work-by-double-clicking-a-ps1-file

Comment: Aquí hay un tutorial que es más reciente.  https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/97162-powershell-scripting-run-script-shortcut.html

Answer (score 0):

Lo que más conviene es producir un shortcut que corra powershell y le indique que powershell debe correr el script indicado.

El siguiente script produce un script ejemplar y un shortcut para correrlo.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
   This script generates MyScript.ps1 and a shortcut to run it.
#>

@'
"This is MyScript,  running"
'@ | Out-file MyScript.ps1

$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut(".\myshortcut.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "powershell.exe"
$Shortcut.Arguments = "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Noexit  -File MyScript.ps1"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

Perdona cualquier error de español.